# PHP Laravel Framework Uploading Image Form Processing

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn to an process image form that uploads images to a database and lets users view the image on the website, this is done using Laravel 4. I must have some sort of bug, because the view doesn't have any errors, but when I select an image to upload and hit the "save" button on my form, nothing happens other than it looks like the form has been refreshed because the file is gone.

Routes

```
// This is for the get event of the index page
Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'index_page',
    'uses' => 'ImageController@getIndex'
));

// This is for the post event of the index page
Route::post('/', array(
    'as' => 'index_page_post',
    'before' => 'csrf',
    'uses' => 'ImageController@postIndex'
));
```

ImageController.php

```
class ImageController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex()
{
    // Let's first load the form view
    return View::make('tpl.index');
}

public function postIndex()
{
    // Let's validate the form first with the rules which are set at the model
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = Photo::$upload_rules;

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    // If the validation fails, we redirect the user to the index page, with errors

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        // If the validation passes, we upload the image to the database and process it
        $image = Input::file('image');

        // This is the original uploaded client name of the image
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        // Because Symfony API does not provide filename
        // without extension, we will be using raw PHP here

        $filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        // We should salt and make an url-friendly version of the file
        $fullname = Str::slug(Str::random(8) . $filename) . '.' .
            $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // We upload the image first to the upload folder, then
        // get make a thumbnail from the uploaded image
        $upload = $image->move
            (Config::get('image.upload_folder'), $fullname);

        Image::make(Config::get('image.thumb_folder').'/'.$fullname)
            ->resize(Config::get('image.thumb_width'), null, true)
            ->save(Config::get('image.thumb_folder').'/'.$fullname);

        // If the file is now uploaded we show a success message
        // otherwise, we show an error

        if ($upload) {
            // image is now uploaded, we first need to add column to the database
            $insert_id = DB::table('photos')->insertGetId(
                array(
                    'title' => Input::get('title'),
                    'image' => $fullname
                    )
                );
            // Now we redirect to the image's permalink
            return Redirect::to(URL::to('snatch/'.$insert_id))
                ->with('success', 'Your image is uploaded successfully!');
        }

        else {
            // Image cannot be uploaded
            return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()
                ->with('error', 'Sorry, the image could not be uploaded.');
        }
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation);
    }
}
```

Image Model

```
class Photo extends Eloquent {

// the variable that sets the table name
protected $table = 'photos';

// the variable that sets the table name
protected $fillable = array('title', 'image');

// the timestamps enabled
public $timestamps = true;

// Rules of the image upload form
public static $upload_rules = array(
        'title' => 'required|min:3',
        'image' => 'required|image'
    );
```

}

The view for the form

```
@extends('frontend_master')

@section('content')

{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'files' => true )) }}

{{ Form::text('title', '', array(
    'placeholder' => 'Please insert your title here')) }}

{{ Form::file('image') }}

{{ Form::submit('save', array('name' => 'send')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

Let me know if you can find any bugs, I'm pretty sure something must be going wrong in my ImageController@postIndex

Thanks for any insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things you need to check out.

1st off, once you updated your composer.json to include the Intervention/Image package. you should run `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoload file.

2ndly, there's a logical error in your controller.

```
Image::make(Config::get('image.thumb_folder').'/'.$fullname)
    ->resize(Config::get('image.thumb_width'), null, true)
    ->save(Config::get('image.thumb_folder').'/'.$fullname);
```

should be

```
Image::make(Config::get('image.image_folder').'/'.$fullname)
    ->resize(Config::get('image.thumb_width'), null, true)
    ->save(Config::get('image.thumb_folder').'/'.$fullname);
```

because you've already moved the image file to image_folder with the code below:

```
$upload = $image->move
    (Config::get('image.upload_folder'), $fullname);
```

Hope this helps.